# Bootstrap 5.2 grid is taking whole width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement this grid wrapping from [Bootstrap 5.2 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/css-grid/#wrapping).

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="grid text-center">
  <div class="g-col-4">.g-col-4</div>
  <div class="g-col-4">.g-col-4</div>
  <div class="g-col-4">.g-col-4</div>
</div>
```

My expectations were that there would be three columns that are equally sized but as you see here, each `.g-col-4` spans the whole width instead of a third of it. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: according [their](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/css-grid/#three-columns) example, looks like you need to provide `https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/assets/css/docs.css` stylesheet as well

Comment: @simo54 I saw that when I inspected the element, but that wasn't part of their getting started documentation. They only specified the three jsdeliver links I added on the snippet above.

Comment: @isherwood Out of curiosity, is there a way for me to enable all features? Like opt-in to all of the available classes so that I don't get tripped up with this again in the future?

Comment: Grid is a rare case. It's left out as a rarely-used feature. Most of what Bootstrap offers is already available. One other exception is [tooltips](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/tooltips/#enable-tooltips), but that's more of a client-side opt-in.

Comment: @isherwood Yes I did see that that's why I also added the `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>` to opt-in to it. So, is what I'm trying to achieve here possible without using grids?

Comment: Probably. I'd start with [flexbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/#enable-flex-behaviors). I use it for 99% of my projects because the concepts and syntax are simpler (IMO). It's enabled by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grid is [opt-in](https://Grid%20is%20opt-in.%20Did%20you%20enable%20the%20CSS%20Grid%20by%20setting%20$enable-cssgrid:%20true?). You need to *enable the CSS Grid by setting `$enable-cssgrid: true`*.